# What methods to replace in helper for Compare Products

Tags: helper

I am trying to replace the helper that provides the compare box with the list of products added to it. My helper is going to get the product ids from a cookie instead of from Magentos session.

My own class in `app/code/local/Mynamespace/Mymodule/Helper/Data.php` extends  `Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract`.

When looking at list.phtml and sidebar.phtml in `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/compare/` they seem to be calling different methods when getting the compare products collection. sidebar.phtml seems to be calling `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Compare_Sidebar->helper('catalog/product_compare')->getItemCollection()` and list.phtml seems to be calling `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Compare_List->getItems()`.

What method(s) do I need to be replacing and in what classes are they present?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there is code duplication between the two core methods for retrieving/building the compare collection (refs [here](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Product/Compare.php#L188) and [here](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/Compare/List.php#L102)), I would suggest that you do the following:

1. Rewrite `Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product_Compare`, overriding its `getItemCollection()` method
2. Rewrite the `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Compare_List` and block's `getItems()` method to  simply return the product compare helper's overridden `getItemsCollection()` method.

Rewrite XPATHs are `global/helpers/catalog/rewrite/product_compare` and `global/blocks/catalog/rewrite/compare_list` respectively.